# How to restart device using blackberry10.0 native development

Tags: blackberry-10

- Hi,i am new to blackberry. Can we restart device programatically
  blackberry 10.0 with native development either with QML or c++?

Comment: I certainly hope not. That is the last thing the platform needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, We can not restart programmatically, they don't provide for security reasons